.NET 8 SDK project references .NET7 SDK dependencies. How to correct?
On my work machine, I created a brand-new project .net 8 sdk project.  A simple console app.  Immediately I get the following error.
.NET 8 SDK VER: 8.0.302
The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 7.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0.

I was poking around the dependencies and noticed that the dependencies are pointing back to .NET 7

As a first step, on my home machine, I just created a brand new .NET 8 (8.0.300) project, same type, simple console app... It does not suffer from the same error.  In fact it contains more dependencies that are correct. References .NET 8
I've poked around various settings but not seeing anything that would cause this.
Also I have scoured the internet trying to find other people who have seen this issue and have not come across anyone else.
Any help is greatly appreciated

The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 7.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0.
open terminal and write    dotnet --list-sdks   to see what sdk you install

Make sure you have at least Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.8
You might already have .NET 8 SDKs - commands dotnet --list-sdks

Thanks Aung...
You reminded me that I needed to update VS2022 after I re-installed it.  I had a couple issues that were contributing to all of this...  I ended up removing both VS2017 and VS2022 yesterday, and re-installed... Forgot that I had read about needing to ensure that the VS 2022 version needed to be at least to a specific version.
Thanks for reminding me!
Rick
